# Why is my Windows 2008 server's free RAM decreasing?

Tags: windows-server-2008

My server's free RAM keeps on going down by several MB a day. Any idea what could be causing that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "free RAM". If you are referring to the Total, Cached, Available, Free values in task manager, then it's great if the free RAM goes down, as long as the "Cached" value is going up. The most likely explanation is that the disk cache is caching disk I/O. Windows will reclaim cached memory if and when an application allocates memory, so it's nothing to worry about. Once a server has been up for many hours, assuming it is doing some work, free RAM will drop to a very low number, and will have a giant disk I/O cache. The disk I/O cache drastically improves system performance.

Look over the Memory values in the Processes tab on all of the processes. Investigate any that seem to have an alarming memory allocation (hundreds of thousands or millions of KB). If they all seem reasonable, then it's most likely expected behavior.